# return column values based on conditions in R

Tags: r

I have 2 columns from my data table where, i need to return the mail IDs where the mark is less than 50.

When tried with the below code, getting error that "Multiple columns returned for vector output".

```
check<-function(R)
{
 s<-list(M)
 if(R > 50) 
 {
 s<-list(M)
 }
 return(s)
}

out<-sapply(R,check);
```

Comment: What is R? what is M? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just guessing: `lapply(R, function(vn) list(DT[vn < 50, M]))` where R are variable names.

Comment: R M New column
20 abc abc
30 xyz xyz
50 aaa 
60 bb 
70 ccc          if column  R<50, only the values corresponding to R in column M  needs to be returned  as new column.